# How did Rolandas Paksas improperly meddle in a privatisation deal?

Tags: european-union, privatization, lithuania

Rolandas Paksas was the first European president to be impeached. He was also the third president of Lithuania after it seceded from the Warsaw pact. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolandas_Paksas#cite_note-nyt-2):

> During his term, concerns arose that he had ties to the Russian mafia. Yuri Borisov, president of the aviation company Avia Baltika, had donated $400,000 to his campaign, and was given Lithuanian citizenship by Paksas' decree. This decree was later ruled to be unconstitutional by Constitutional Court of Lithuania.
>
> Paksas' connections were investigated by the Department of Security. In early 2004, the Seimas [Lithuanian Parliament] started impeachment proceedings against him. On 31 March 2004 the Constitutional Court of Lithuania found him guilty of violating the constitution and his oath of office. On 6 April 2004, the Parliament (Seimas) voted on three charges:
>
> a. that he had leaked classified information about his investigation to Borisov
>
> b. that he had improperly restored Borisov's citizenship
>
> c. and that he had interfered in a privatization transaction.

Euroactiv also [notes](https://www.euractiv.com/section/enlargement/news/lithuania-s-president-rolandas-paksas-is-impeached/):

> Out of the minimum of 85 votes needed of the 141-seat parliament, 86 MPs voted that Paksas illegally granted Lithuanian citizenship to Borisov and leaked state secrets. 89 deputies voted that he improperly meddled in a privatisation deal.

What was the nature of this interference in a privatisation transaction?

Comment: Wikipedia article in Lithuanian seems to be more informative (google translate works well enough): https://lt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolando_Pakso_apkalta